# Shouldn't the Ninja Turtles have a Radar Sense?

Tags: comics, mutant, daredevil, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

It's *heavily* implied in the **Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles** source material that the canister of mutagen that caused their mutation is the *same exact chemical* that gave **DareDevil** his powers. This can be seen here:

[image]

[image]

But if this was the case..... *shouldn't the Ninja Turtles all have enhance senses and a radar sense?*

Granted, there are obvious legal copyright issues between the TMNT creators and Marvel, and this was done as an obvious omage to DareDevil, but considering that Matt Murdock only got a few drops in his eyes and got his powers, and the Turtles got the stuff *all over them,* wouldn't it make sense that they have *at least* some slightly sharper senses?

Comment: Not exactly. OOU explanation: turtles’ and Human DNA is not the same. Hence the mutation in two different species can not be the same. In-universe: there are several instances like this.. eg, FF4, inhumans, mutants.. each of these groups have the same source that created them, but they have completely different abilities. And this is when they’re all humans. So turtles not having same powers as Matt Murdock is obvious

Comment: @Shreedhar that may make sense for most versions...but what about the 80s cartoon? Hamato yoshi _was_ human, and all he did was mutate into a rat [which in itself is odd; he was last around the turtles, so should have been _at least_ some kinda turtle -rat hybrid]. And even that being the case, *Matt* then shouldn't just be enhanced, but actually **mutated** on some level, as the same mutagenic substance made contact with sensitive ocular tissue. Even if we go by your explanation, then all of the turtles should be mutated differently, but it had the _exact affect_ on all of them, so again, odd

Comment: Complete opinions on this. Sorry, fun but not winning any points here.